# How to append my web scraping data into a list?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, append

Using Python:
I would like to scrape this website https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster for the heights of all the players. Here is my code. After extracting the heights successfully, I am not able to append them into a list. When I try to do this, the list executes as ['6'3"', '6'3"', '6'3"'] instead of the 23 heights I need. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Creating empty lists to hold the heights in inches and original scraped heights
height_inches = []
height_list = []

heights = soup.find_all('span', class_= "sidearm-roster-player-height")

#For some reason, the 23 heights printed twice, hence -23 from the length
for i in range(0, (len(heights)-23)):
  {
      print(heights[i].get_text())
  }
#^This line of code allows me to see all the heights in a normal list^

#Trying to append the newly found heights in a list
height_list.append(heights[i].get_text())
print(height_list)
```

Comment: The `list.append(x)` line of code should be inside the `for` loop.

Comment: ```for i in heights:
    height_list.append(i.get_text())``` Also, you don't need to put curly braces in Python.

Answer (score 0):

When building a list with a `for` loop, you need the `.append` to happen *inside* the loop:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Creating empty lists to hold the heights in inches and original scraped heights
height_inches = []
height_list = []

heights = soup.find_all('span', class_= "sidearm-roster-player-height")

#For some reason, the 23 heights printed twice, hence -23 from the length
for i in range(0, (len(heights)-23)):
    height_text = heights[i].get_text()
    height_list.append(height_text)
    print(height_text)

print(height_list)
```